# Reverse for 'home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s)

Tags: python, django, django-urls

A brief description of what I am trying to do is I am trying to access my 'home.html' web page (which exists on the home app) by clicking on the logo on the 'rates.html' web page (which exists on the rates app), the way I tried to achieve this is as follows.

I looked at the other similar problems here and they all seem to forget to specify the namespace part on the appname\urls.py part of the code. I feel like I have done this properly specifying app_name = '[namespace]' into the urls.py.

The exact error that it shows specific to my problem is:

Reverse for 'home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

the error highlights a line of html code on 'rate.html':

```
<div id="logoholder">
    <a href="**{% url 'getrate:home' %}**"><img src="{%static 
    'home/images/transparentWatermark.png' %}" width="40" height="40" 
    style="margin:5px 10px"></a>
</div>
```

getrate\urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

app_name = 'getrate'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.ViewRate, name='rate'),
    url(r'^home/', include('home.urls', namespace='home')),
]
```

home\urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

app_name = 'home'

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.ViewHome, name='home'),
]
```

mysite\urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home/', include('home.urls', namespace='home')),
    url(r'^getrate/', include('getrate.urls', namespace='getrate')),
]
```

What I must be interpreting wrong about this is the rate.html has a company logo I can click which triggers the getrate\urls.py via {% url 'getrate:home' %}. The getrate\urls.py code includes the home\urls.py within it. This part is triggered as it has the namespace home on that line of code. Now it looks through the home\urls.py and finally ends its regex matching. Let me know how I am wrong.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because such a url does not exist!

First of all you are causing unwanted confusion for yourself by mixing `namespace`s and `app_name`s please note

> Support for the app_name argument is deprecated and will be removed in
>   Django 2.0. Specify the app_name as explained in URL namespaces and
>   included URLconfs instead

ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/

Secondly, I really don't see why you need to have three separate urls.py files (unless this is an app that you are building for redistribution). A single main urls.py is perfectly good enough since you have only three urls in total.

If you want to persist with this please remove the `app_name` and use only the namespace parameter and try again.

Comment: "You are getting that error because such a url does not exist!" -The way i understand it is It is getting the /home/ url.

Comment: Well obviously it isn't. How else would you be getting that error?

Comment: As I have mentioned in my answer, you have conflicting namespace and app_name directive. Leave out the app_names

Comment: I wrote a whole paragraph on the comment above...I somehow failed to submit it! I am using 3 URLs as I thought that is the best practice to have one for each app.

Comment: i removed the app_name part from both home\urls.py and getrate\urls.py. Now the rate.html page loads and does not give me the error above. When I click on logo however it fails to bring me to the home page. error message is now:                                                             Using the URLconf defined in WinsWayTransport.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^home/
^getrate/ ^$ [name='rate']
The current URL, getrate/{ % url 'home' %}, didn't match any of these.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer fixed the direct problem, it did not achieve the function I was trying to perform (which was redirecting to an html page on another app). What I was not understanding properly was the url workflow. I thought from whichever app you use url it looks through that app's urls.py code first instead of the main website urls.py code.

The actual workflow is going from mysite/urls.py --> (if importing and using includes library) --> app1/urls.py --> app2/urls.py --> app#/urls.py. So always starts at the main urls.py

Due to the misunderstanding of this concept my error was trying to link each urls.py code from each app to each other leading to all kinds of errors, infinite loops, etc.